# Gatsbyjs + Directus how to get image from content?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, directus, ssg

I connected gatsby and directus. everything is ok, but...

I have html text field with name "content" in directus, it has images inside. how do i get them in gatsby?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

1. I created a multiplefiles field in Directus in the Article named "imagelist" there indicated the same images that I use in the article.
2. Now gatsby gives me an array of images in GraphQL.
3. Wrote a `CustomImage` component for the image, where I check the id.
4. Used the `overrides` option to replace the `img` tag in the `Markdown` component.

So, my code looks that:

**layout props:**

```
interface ArticleImage {
  directus_files_id: {
    id: string;
    imageFile: IGatsbyImageData;
  }
}

interface BlogLayoutProps {
  title: string;
  annotation: string;
  imageData: IGatsbyImageData;
  allImages: Array<ArticleImage>;
  content: string;
}
```

**custom image component:**

```
const CustomImage = (props) => {

    const { alt, width, height, src } = props;
    const image = allImages.find(i => src.indexOf(i.directus_files_id.id) !== -1);

    if (image) {
      const imgData = getImage(image.directus_files_id.imageFile);
      imgData.width = +width;
      imgData.height = +height;
      return <GatsbyImage image={imgData} alt={alt}/>;
    }

    return <img src={src} width={width} height={height} alt={alt} />
  };
```

**in layout component:**

```
<StyledContent>
      <Markdown
        options={{
          overrides: {
            img: {
              component: CustomImage,
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        {content}
      </Markdown>
    </StyledContent>
```

**query in page:**

```
query MyQuery {
  directus {
    article_by_id(id: "26434049-7bb4-46d3-8ad1-c04973b9cf71") {
      id
      category {
        id
        title
      }
      title
      description
      content
      image {
        id
        width
        height
        imageFile {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
      imagelist {
        directus_files_id {
          id
          imageFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope someone will help my solution or push him to new thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display your image inside the raw HTML (`content`) you will need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or use a markdown parser. The `imageFile` node can be isolated and print alone.

You just need to use a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) to fetch your data like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';

 const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  console.log("Your data is", data);

  return (
    <div>
    Your image is: <img src={data.article.image.imageFile.publicURL} alt="" />
    Your content is:
    <Markdown>{data.article.content}</Markdown>
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query directus{
    article {
       id
       title
       description
       content
       image {
        imageFile {
          publicURL
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

*Note: I've based my query in your GraphQL schema, tweak it to adapt it to yours.*

Your queried data is stored inside `props.data` (destructured as `data` in this case), then you just need to get the needed node in each case. For your image, you need to keep nesting the object until your reach `publicURL`.

Regarding the rest of the content, I've used [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) library which is quite straightforward to use, but you can omit it and use directly  `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or another library.

Comment: How gatsby will load images inside the content field?

Comment: It's not Gatsby, it's the markdown parser (if you use `markdown-to-jsx)` or React (if you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`). And it's because you ar fetching all the raw HTML (`<p>`, `<img>`, etc)

Comment: Thanks! But I am doubting image will load into static directory by gatsby and i will get not-working src. But I will look to 'markdown-to-jsx'!

Comment: Gatsby clones everything in the `/static` folder into the public one, so the image will be available on your site (the source of the image I mean). I think it will work alone if the image is present.

Comment: i wrapped content into markdown, work good, but src =  http://localhost:8055/assets/7a5a803c-0af8-4196-b899-9dedb875648e if i stop directus image will broken, i think need change standart img to gatsby img component like that

Comment: You can't change `img` to `GatsbyImage`on the fly. Gatsby image requires more data and Gatsby needs to treat the image to create the node. What's the issue about your current `src`?

Comment: current `src` reffer to image on directus host. need load image to gatsby `static` path